# Joining an Excel tabel to single polygons of a feature layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, excel

I am trying to associate the contents of an external Excel spreadsheet with individual polygons of a feature class.

I have a layer that has hundreds of polygons. I also have an Excel spreadsheet that contains several rows that can be assigned to individual polygons. Now my goal is to join all rows with the same ID as the corresponding polygon, so that the contents of the Excel table are included in the attribute table of the polygon. Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, in a number of ways. What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Permanent join - ["Join Field"](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm), Temporary join - ["Add Join"](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm)